# No Replace function with COMMAND+ALT+F shortcut in Sublime Text on mac

Tags: osx-mavericks, sublime-text-2

CMD+SHIFT+E (which is for Replace Next function) works fine. Pressing CMD+ALT+F doesnt even highlight the Find menu momentarily. I can't work out where is the shortcut going, or what's highjacking it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the [`FindKeyConflicts`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/FindKeyConflicts) plugin via Package Control. Then, open the Command Palette with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and type in ***`findkey`*** to bring up the **`FindKeyConflicts: All Conflicts`** option. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and a new tab will open listing all the potential conflicts. Not all of them are real, as some may apply to different scopes or different situations, such as the entries at the top of the list for `"`.

Search down through the list for `super+alt+f` or `alt+super+f`, and hopefully it'll be on there, showing which plugin is conflicting with the keymap. Then, you can edit that plugin's `.sublime-keymap` file (or remove the plugin entirely, if you want) and you should be all set.